# Why my app is not compatible with my own phone in google play

Tags: android, developer-console

I know this questions has been asked a lot but I really don't get any answer
My app is not compatible with any phone:
[Developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhYT5.png)

this is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="amaigh.biolotel">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity

        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Settings" />
    <activity android:name=".Chooser" />
    <activity android:name=".PdfReader"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

When I Analyze my app with android studio I get this manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.0"
package="amaigh.biolotel"
platformBuildVersionCode="25"
platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="amaigh.biolotel.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="0x2" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="amaigh.biolotel.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:theme="@ref/0x7f08003b"
    android:label="@ref/0x7f06003d"
    android:icon="@ref/0x7f02006d"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f0800d7"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f06003d"
        android:name="amaigh.biolotel.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="0x4a0">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f08003c"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f06003d"
        android:name="amaigh.biolotel.MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name="amaigh.biolotel.Settings" />

    <activity
        android:name="amaigh.biolotel.Chooser" />

    <activity
        android:name="amaigh.biolotel.PdfReader" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x0103000f"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="0xfb0" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f080125"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <action
                android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category
                android:name="amaigh.biolotel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
                                  android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter
            android:priority="-500">

            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="amaigh.biolotel.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@ref/0x7f0a0006" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Use latest sdk for compilation i.e. android 7.1.1 .. always compile with latest sdk and platform tools to ensure that it will be compatible with all devices

Comment: Your app min sdk support is 16, if your old phone sdk version is less than 16 then your app wont work in it

Comment: Can you please remove the code - <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />   . And then try it

Comment: Still the same think it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this code in manifest.. if you are using android studio

just check in your app.gridle file min and target SDK api no